# Are gates in qiskit necessarily unitary?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-circuit

We are programming with Qiskit and for our research project we need to insert non-unitary gates within a quantum circuit.

1. Is the unitarity of gates a mandatory property required to run the code without raising errors?
2. Are there specific parts of the Qiskit source code that can be modified in order to implement non-unitary gates without the need to change the whole Qiskit framework?

Comment: See https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/20695/9858

Comment: See also https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/15805/13991

Answer (score 4):

Non-unitary gate is a bit of an oxymoron for reasons explained [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/23826/non-unitary-gates-in-qiskit#comment31258_23826) and [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/23826/non-unitary-gates-in-qiskit#comment31267_23826). Qiskit support non-unitary *instructions*. `Gate`s are `Instruction`s subclasses. A gate, like `XGate` is an instruction, but not every instruction, such as `Reset`, is a gate:

```
from qiskit.circuit import Gate, Instruction, Reset
issubclass(Reset, Instruction)  # True
issubclass(Reset, Gate)  # False

issubclass(XGate, Instruction)  # True
issubclass(XGate, Gate)  # True
```

So Qiskit already supports the notion of non-unitary instruction. You can create your own instruction with `to_instruction`. For example, this is a "reset to 1" instruction:

1. Create a circuit:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
reset_to_one = QuantumCircuit(1, name="reset to 1")
reset_to_one.reset(0)
reset_to_one.x(0)
print(reset_to_one)
```

```
        ┌───┐
q: ─|0>─┤ X ├
        └───┘
```

2. Convert that circuit into a instruction:

```
reset_to_one_inst = reset_to_one.to_instruction()
```

3. Add your instruction into a circuit:

```
circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
circuit.h(0)
circuit.cx(0, 1)
circuit.append(reset_to_one, [1])
circuit.measure_all()
print(circuit)
```

```
        ┌───┐                    ░ ┌─┐   
   q_0: ┤ H ├──■─────────────────░─┤M├───
        └───┘┌─┴─┐┌────────────┐ ░ └╥┘┌─┐
   q_1: ─────┤ X ├┤ reset to 1 ├─░──╫─┤M├
             └───┘└────────────┘ ░  ║ └╥┘
meas: 2/════════════════════════════╩══╩═
                                    0  1
```

In this case, $q_1$ will be reset to 1 before being measured into $meas_1$. `reset to 1` is a non-unitary instruction.

Comment: Thanks @luciano, your answer was really helpful! It seems that with your solution, one can define a new instruction as a composition of predefined Qiskit instructions. We are facing a slightly different problem: we know the entries of a non-unitary matrix and we want to define the instruction that corresponds to this matrix. Is this possible?

Comment: Also interested to see if this is possible. Need to define non-unitary instructions from a matrix.

Comment: Qiskit does not support non-unitary-matrix-defined operations (yet?). What's your use-case for them? Synthesis? Simulation? Feel free to make a case as a feature request https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit/issues/new?template=FEATURE_REQUEST.yaml

Comment: I'm looking at implementing the trajectories method for simulating a noisy circuit (https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/23400/19585), and have Kraus operators that are not necessarily unitary.

Answer (score 1):

One can define a non-unitary matrix as a density matrix, in the case it is hermitian positive-definite. It seems qiskit does not check the trace condition.
However, it would be nice to know a way of building an instruction from a non-unitary matrix. All examples I found of non-unitary instructions where built from circuits.